# Is it possible to mock an interface, which includes two functions without any return values?

Tags: go, interface, mocking

Is it possible to mock the interface ClassFunction with libaries such as mockery? I'm not sure because FunctionOne and FunctionTwo have no return values.

```
package srcFunctions

import "fmt"

type ClassToUse struct {
    NumberOne int
    NumberTwo int
}

type ClassFunctions interface {
    FunctionOne()
    FunctionTwo()
}

func (c *ClassToUse) FunctionOne() {
    c.NumberOne = 1
    fmt.Println("FunctionOne: NumberOne=", c.NumberOne)
}

func (c *ClassToUse) FunctionTwo() {
    c.NumberTwo = 2
    fmt.Println("FunctionTwo: NumberTwo=", c.NumberTwo)
}
```

I've been stuck with this problem for a long time and don't know what to do next. I've tried everything, looked on the internet, in books and everything, but nothing helped me. I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: "with libaries such as mockery" Why? Your mock is literally 4 lines, so why use tools to write these 4 lines?

Comment: It would be interesting to know in what context you use that `ClassFunctions` interface... For once, I agree with @Volker: you may not need an external dependency to mock/stub something so small.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can use https://github.com/golang/mock for such needs.

First, you need to add a `gomock` annotation to your code with two flags:

1. source - file path where the target interface is specified;
2. destination - path where to create mock file.

```
package srcFunctions

import "fmt"

type ClassToUse struct {
    NumberOne int
    NumberTwo int
}

//go:generate mockgen -destination mock/class_functions.go -source=class_functions.go

type ClassFunctions interface {
    FunctionOne()
    FunctionTwo()
}

func (c *ClassToUse) FunctionOne() {
    c.NumberOne = 1
    fmt.Println("FunctionOne: NumberOne=", c.NumberOne)
}

func (c *ClassToUse) FunctionTwo() {
    c.NumberTwo = 2
    fmt.Println("FunctionTwo: NumberTwo=", c.NumberTwo)
}
```

Then, run the command `go generate` in your package folder to create a mock file. After the mock file appears, you can use it in your tests. Here's an example of it's usage:

```
package srcFunctions

import (
    mock_srcFunctions "stackoverflow/srcFunctions/mock"
    "testing"

    gomock "github.com/golang/mock/gomock"
)

func Foo(cf ClassFunctions) {
    cf.FunctionOne()
    cf.FunctionTwo()
}

func TestClassFunctions(t *testing.T) {
    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    classFunctionsMock := mock_srcFunctions.NewMockClassFunctions(ctrl)

    // catching first function
    classFunctionsMock.EXPECT().FunctionOne()

    // catching second function
    classFunctionsMock.EXPECT().FunctionTwo()

    Foo(classFunctionsMock)
}
```